# Error import win32api for Python 64bit-3.4.3.6

Tags: python-2.7, winapi, python-3.4, win32com

I am trying to modify a Python script I wrote for **Python 64bit 2.7** to use it with **Python 64bit 3.4.3.6**. This program is using `from win32com.client import Dispatch`.
When running it with Python 64bit 2.7 it works perfectly well, but with Python 64bit 3.4 I have the following error:

```
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I checked in *WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6\python-3.4.3.amd64\Lib\site-packages* and there are three folders: *\win32*, *\win32com* and *\win32comext*.
I was able to find a file called `win32api.pyd` in *\win32*.

NB: I found similar topics but none of them really answered the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the line works under WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.4Qt5, but it should work on WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.6 too.